# Event bubbling weirdness

Tags: apache-flex

I'm seeing some weirdness in event bubbling, which suggests I don't really understand how this is supposed to work.

I have a component which extends DataGroup, and it's item renderer dispatches an event (which bubbles).

```
// MyRenderer.mxml
<s:ItemRenderer>
    <s:Button click='dispatchEvent(new Event('customEvent',true))' />
</s:ItemRenderer>
```

The DataGroup adds a listener for the event to itself.

```
// MyDataGroup.mxml
<s:DataGroup  itemRenderer="MyRenderer" creationComplete='onCreationComplete()'>
   <fx:Metadata>
       [Event(name='customEvent',type='flash.events.Event')]
   </fx:Metadata>
   <fx:Script>
      private function onCreationComplete():void
      {
          addEventListener('customEvent',onCustomEvent);
      }
      private function onCustomEvent(event:Event):void
      {
      }
   </fx:Script>
</s:DataGroup>
```

The Parent of the datagroup is also adding a listener for the event.

```
// MyComponent.mxml
<s:Group>
    <MyDataGroup customEvent='onCustomEventHandler()' />
</s:Group>
```

I'd have expected that the handler registered in `MyDataGroup` should catch the event first, then the handler in `MyComponent`.

However, I'm seeing the reverse - ie., caught in `MyComponent`, then in `MyDataGroup`.  When caught, `event.phase == EventPhase.BUBBLING`.

What's going on here?  Why am I seeing this behaviour?

I'm using Flex 4.0.

Comment: MyDataGroup does not have a handler function for the event listener.  I assume that is a copy & paste typo, as I wouldn't have expected your code to actually compile with that error.  Please specify which version of the SDK you're using.  You're understanding of what should work is similar to mine, so the behavior is unexpected. Is each component in separate files? Or are you doing things in-line?

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to correct the error (yep, just a copy 'n' paste issue).  All classes have their own mxml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the problem is that both of your event listeners are listening to the same instance on the MyDataGroup component.

If you add the an event listener to MyComponent instead of MyDataGroup, you'll get expected behavior:

```
<s:Group xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
         xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
         xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" width="400" height="300" 
          initialize="group1_initializeHandler(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            public function onCustomEventHandler(event:Event):void{
                trace('my Component handler');
            }

            protected function group1_initializeHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                // add the event listener to 'this' 
                this.addEventListener('customEvent',onCustomEventHandler);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <martyPitt:MyDataGroup id="dataGroup"  />
    <!-- The event listener here was listening on the myDataGroup instance, not on the MyComponent instance customEvent="onCustomEventHandler(event)"  -->
</s:Group>
```

I suspect the event listeners--even though not in the same component--were firing based on the order they were added.  You'd have to examine the generated ActionScript with the compiler argument '-keep' to figure that out specifically.  I suspect your in-line listener (MyComponent) is added in the MyDataGroup constructor.  Since the other listener is added in the MyDataGroup a creationComplete handler, the MyComponent listener fires first.

Comment: I think you're right on this, I came to the same conclusion after reading the docs and playing with some code

Comment: Another option is to set the event priority to 1 when you add your event listener inside your custom component. Because Flex assign automatically a priority of 0 for the inline event listener declaration, it means the component handler will be called first.

Answer (score 0):

Strange behaviour indeed.

Actually, when you add an event listener inline (in your example :

```
  <MyDataGroup
 customEvent='onCustomEventHandler()'
 />
```

), the framework add an event listener on the capture phase. So it's an expected behaviour it enters in your parent handler first. What I don't undestand is that the eventPhase is equals to EventPhase.BUBBLE_PHASE although it should display EventPhase.CAPTURE_PHASE.

Comment: -1 I was able to take Marty's code and replicate his results w/ the Flex 4.0 SDK.  EventPhase is definitely showing '3' which according to docs is the bubbling phase. ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html ); and event listeners execute and the unexpected order.  Bizarre

Comment: I know, that's what I was trying to say actually.
In my code, it goes first in the parent handler, then in the component. But this is what you can expect because as I said, when you do customEvent="onCustomEventHandler()", it adds an event for the capture phase. (I remember reading that in the docs) So I interpret the results as : it enters first in the parent during the capture phase and then in the component on the bubble phase. The strange thing is that it displays BUBBLE_PHASE. We could agree at least that there something wrong going on ;)

Comment: Ok so after reading carefully the doc, I was definitely wrong :
it says : R"egistering an event listener inline provides less flexibility than using the addEventListener() method to register event listeners. The drawbacks are that you cannot set the useCapture or priority properties on the Event object and that you cannot remove the listener once you add it." So I guess it means it adds an event listener for the bubbling phase and that it probably set the priority to a high number